How does CAN transceivers output CANH=3.5V and CANL=1.5V?
This is a questions that has been asked but did not find a clear answer. How it is the 3.5V achieved on CAN_H? Assuming there is 0.5V voltage drop on the internal diode, 0.1V on the internal MOSFET and 5V supply for CAN transceiver that would give us: 5V-0.5V-0.1V=4.4V. Where is the additional 0.9V drop coming from? Is the Rds MOSFET that high? Assuming a termination of 60Ohm with a 3.5V CAN_H and 1.5V CAN_L level we would have around 33mA current draw (3.5V-1.5V/60Ohm) so to achieve the 3.5V CAN_H level the MOSFET would need to have an Rds=Vds/33mA=1V/33mA=30Ohm. Can the internal Rds of MOSFET be that high and vary that much (cause CAN_H level is specified in between 3.5V and 5V) or is something wrong in my understanding?

Thank you!

please edit your post ... add a reference to the source of the picture

Welcome to EE.SE. Your question seems to be an exact duplicate of the one you made a screenshot of, which has already been answered. To recap: The CAN transmitter doesn't need to output 3.5V, it only needs to output at least 3.5V. It's fine if it outputs something between 3.5V and 5V. The same applies to the low level (at most 1.5V, not exactly 1.5V). The additional voltage difference is a safety margin.

Thank you for your answer Jonathan. What is not clear for me out of that post and from your answer is why there is that safety margin so high. Is it because of so high variations in Rds? And if so, what causes that?

@JonathanS. Iirc it doesn't even need to reach 3.5V. The 3.3V supplied transceivers abuse the voltage level spec to make CANH 3.3V. I think there was some app note from TI claiming that this was compliant but I don't remember any details.
